# Reconstruct numpy array using indexing

Tags: python, numpy, indexing

I have a `numpy` array of `3*k` elements, where `k` is an integer. For instance, for `k=3` I have the array `A`. Below, `x`, `y`, and `z` are filled by drawing elements from `A` as shown in the following example:

```
import numpy as np

A = np.arange(9)
>> array([0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8])

x = A[0::3]
>> array([0, 3, 6])

y = A[1::3]
array([1, 4, 7])

z = A[2::3]
>> array([2, 5, 8])
```

Now, I want to use `x`, `y`, and `z` so as to reconstruct `A`. Is there any convenient way of doing this without using `for` loops?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do

```
np.array([x,y,z]).T.reshape(-1)
```

Comment: It works like a charm! Many thanks.

Comment: Feel free to accept the answer..if you like :)

Comment: Sure, but you answered too quickly... So you need to wait 5 more minutes :)

Comment: oh sorry! Didnt know that. One more thing, can you check for some other value of k (other than 3)

Comment: Yeah, it seems that it works for any integer k.